# Is there a way to take conditions for for loop as an input in python? I am having trouble with this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

I recently had an idea of doing sigma(Σ) using python
So, I wrote this code.

```
def sigma(i,target,condition='i'):
    if condition=='i':
        a=0
        for f in range(i,target+1): #the loop sums all the numbers from i to the target given
            a+=f
        print(a)
'''if user enters a condition than,
every number will follow condition and then be added to each other'''
    else:
        lis=list()
        condition for i in range(i,target+1):
            lis.append(i)
        print(sum(lis))
```

but the code I wrote above just gives me a wrong output as it takes the variable condition as type 'string'.
The problem is actully to take the argument condition not as a string
for example, let's say user entered:

```
sigma(1,100,condition='i'*2)
```

so the code should run for loop like this:

```
i*2 for i in range(i, target+1)
```

but it runs like this:

```
'ii' for i in range(i, target+1)
```

Comment: The `else` part of your code is completely unclear. What does `i*2 for i in range(i, target+1)` mean?

Comment: i changed the code a little and added some comments. the loop actually adds all the numbers from i to the target but after applying a certain condition on them. let's say user entered sigma(1,100,condition=i*2) so it should add all numbers from 1 to 100 after multiplying them by 2. please unflag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I can understand, you should pass an anonymous function as argument to accomplish what you are looking for.
Consider that this is not a valid syntax: `i*2 for i in range(i, target+1)`, so I consider it as a pseudo code explained by your comment.

You should change your method in this way:

```
def sigma(i, target, condition='i'):
    if condition=='i':
        a=0
        for f in range(i,target+1):
            a+=f
        print(a)
    else:
        lis=list()
        for i in range(i, target+1):
            lis.append(i)
        print(condition(sum(lis)))
```

So that if you call `sigma(1,100,'i') #=> 5050` you fall in the true part of the statement.

For the false part of the statement you need to call the method passing a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) as parameter:

```
sigma(1,100, lambda i: 2*i) #=> 10100
```

It happens that the argument `condition` when passed as lambda works as if it was defined as:

```
def condition(i):
    return 2 * i
```

---

I would like to point out that the sum of the first n natural numbers is given by a math formula, so you don't need a loop:

```
n * (n + 1) // 2
```

Also should be better to return a value than to print.

I'd rewrite the method:

```
def sigma_2(i, target, condition=None):
    sum_i_to_target = (target*(target+1)-(i-1)*i)//2
    if condition is not None:
        return condition(sum_i_to_target)
    else: # need to check that condition is a lambda function
        return sum_i_to_target
```

So call this way:

```
sigma_2(2, 20) #=> 209
sigma_2(2, 20, lambda i: 2*i) #=> 418
```

Answer (score 0):

You've initialized `i` from what I can see from your code as a string.

If you would like for the compiler to read it as int then initialize `i` as int.

For example:

`i=1`